# Clean old release files in Sentry

Tags: logging, monitoring, centralized-logging

I'm self-hosting Sentry 8 and `/var/lib/sentry/files` grew to a significant size. I tried launching a script to go through each project's releases via the API, select those older than *X* days, and remove all files relating to those releases. It seemed to remove a bunch of stuff (the majority of the releases was older than my threshold) but the size of the `files` directory didn't shrink that much, even after running `sentry cleanup` after my script was done. How can I reclaim that space?